# Linq to ADO Entity query

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I've had a fair search of some help, but I'm having a real load of trouble wrapping my head around this.

Basically I want to collapse an EntityCollection down into a String to display it with the related record in a single row of a gridview, but I've no idea how, or if it's even the best thing to do.

My entity diagram (see below); I want to grab objects from loom_Charms, however many meet the criteria, displaying with each a flattened string of loom_CharmCosts, loom_charmMinimums, pretty much all of the *-Many relationships there, and shove them all in a gridview. Having spent hours trying to fiddle around to see if there's a better way, I'm giving up and asking for help"

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/nud06.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this -- you'll need to flatten out the Costs by using something like String.Join().

```
var charmsAndCosts = context.Ioom_Charms
    .Where(c => c.xxxxx = whatever)
    .Select(c =>  new {
        Charm = c,
        Costs = String.Join(",", c.Ioom_CharmCosts.Select(cc => cc.charmCost.ToString()).ToArray())});
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." with this. It's so irritating; I would have though there'd be an easy way to do this!
EDIT: Oops, nevermind, it works in Linq to ADO, just not SQL. Can someone tell me if this is a particularly desirable approach, though? Can I avoid it by doing something clever?

Comment: Call .ToArray() after your .Where() statement.